# Will the download from Epic Games resume after hibernate

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, epic-games-launcher

I have already tried shutdown and restart but it resets download to 0%. i am specific about hibernating my laptop. P.S. I have tried the answer of ***Bxxt*** from question by ***jack wilshere*** but it did not work.

Comment: This question has been asked a number of time already, so please don't ask it again.

Comment: Wrigglenite but I am asking a different question. I am asking about the hibernation state.